# Are all GHZ-states isotropic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, symmetry, quantum-entanglement

Are Greenberger-Horne-Zeilinger (GHZ) states defined by:

$$ |GHZ_{d}^{M}\rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} |i^{ (1)}\rangle \otimes \cdot \cdot \cdot \otimes |{i}^{ (M) }\rangle $$

by default isotropic, or is that only true for the case $d=2$?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "isotropic"?

Comment: invariant under rotation of the coordinate system

Comment: Note that was it called "isotropic states" in entanglement theory is *not* isotropic.

Comment: Wait, can you give an example of a GHZ state with $d>2$?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch what is the meaning of isotropic state in entanglement theory and can you add it to complete your answer?

Comment: @user1936752 https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/isotropic-state -- as it is not part of the question I won't add it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not even the $d=2$ state is isotropic, for any $M$.

For two spin-1/2 particles, there are four basis states, which we will label by their total spin $S$ and spin along the $z$-axis $m_s$ as $|S,m_s\rangle$:

$$|1,1\rangle=|00\rangle$$
$$|1,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$$
$$|1,-1\rangle=|11\rangle$$
$$|0,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)$$

As you can see, these states can be organized into a *triplet* of spin-1 states and a *singlet* spin-0 state. **Only the spin singlet can be isotropic**, since only a state with a total spin of 0 can give the same results for any arbitrary spin measurement. The GHZ state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1,1\rangle+|1,-1\rangle)$, so it isn't isotropic. In fact, we can treat it for the moment as a spin-1 particle with the state vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,1)$, for the basis $|+_z\rangle,|0_z\rangle,|-_z\rangle$ of states with spin 1, 0, and -1 along the $z$-axis, respectively.

We can, in fact, directly demonstrate that spin measurements along different axes will give different results. The spin operator along the $z$-axis for a spin-1 particle is:

$$S_z=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

So the expectation value of the spin of the GHZ state along the $z$-axis is:

$$\langle S_z\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}(1-1)=0$$

This is as expected, since the GHZ state has equal amplitudes for the spin-up and spin-down components along the $z$-axis. However, if we look along the $x$-axis, the spin operator is:

$$S_x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

which means that the expectation value of spin along the $x$-axis is:

$$\langle S_x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}=0$$

In turn, the expectation value of the $S_z^2$ and $S_x^2$ operators are:

$$\langle S_z^2\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1$$

$$\langle S_x^2\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&2&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}(2+2)=2$$

Ah-ha! We have spotted a difference. In particular, the *uncertainty* in the spin measured along the $z$-axis and $x$-axis are different:

$$\Delta S_z=\sqrt{\langle S_z^2\rangle-\langle S_z\rangle^2}=1$$

$$\Delta S_x=\sqrt{\langle S_x^2\rangle-\langle S_x\rangle^2}=\sqrt{2}$$

This means that the GHZ state definitely does not look the same along the $z$-axis and along the $x$-axis, hence it isn't isotropic.

---

This procedure can be generalized to arbitrarily many qubits: consider them as a single system of spin $M/2$, examine the states that arise for such a system, and examine the uncertainty in the spin along the $x$-axis and $z$-axis. There are two very general takeaways:

- For odd $M$, **there are no isotropic states with $d=2$**. At all. This is because you cannot add together an odd number of copies of $1/2$ to get $0$, so the $|0,0\rangle$ state (which is the only isotropic state) is not possible.
- For even $M$, **the $d=2$ GHZ state is not an isotropic state**. It will always look different along the $z$-axis than it does along the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

This is not even true for $d=2$ and $M=2$: The state
$$
|00\rangle+|11\rangle
$$
is not invariant under rotations - e.g., applying 
$$
U=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i\\ i &1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
will map it to 
$$
(U\otimes U)(|00\rangle+|11\rangle) = 
|00\rangle+i|01\rangle+ i|10\rangle+|11\rangle\ .
$$

Indeed, the orbit of $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$ under rotations $U\otimes U$ is spanned by the three triplet states,
$$
|00\rangle\pm|11\rangle \mbox{ and } |01\rangle+|10\rangle
$$

On the other hand, it is known (and easy to check) that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d \vert i,i\rangle = (U\otimes \bar U)
\sum_{i=1}^d \vert i,i\rangle\ ,
$$
and thus, for $M=2$ the state will be invariant under all unitaries with *real* entries (i.e., orthogonal matrices).

Comment: But $(H\otimes H)(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)=|++\rangle+|--\rangle=|00\rangle+|11\rangle$, no? What am I missing?

Comment: @glS Ouch! And the worst thing is, I should have known better -- after all, maximally entangled states $\sum |i,i\rangle$ are invariant under $U\otimes \bar U$ (-> isotropic states!), and thus also under $U\otimes U$ as long as $U$ is real.